# Asking for the OpenBLAS installation

Tags: openblas

I was going to install the OpenBLAS on Mac OS but seems failed at the end.
First I downloaded the source and extracted that and then input the 'make' commands on terminal. However, I cannot run 'make install' after it, where it shows

```
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

. The OpenBLAS installation seems not finished. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to install it? It's just a library, link it with your code, and you're done, there is no need to install.

Comment: Thanks for noticing me. I just follow some tutorials which state the commands I should type.